# Vue bind to dynamic json node(create if not exists)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm trying to make `v-model` to bind to dynamic node in a json object (if not exists create node). The response node will come as a config.

Eg:

```
 <v-text-field :="responseNode"></v-text-field>
```

where `responseNode` will be some string like `dataObject.Response.ParentObject.ChildVal`

So I will expect something like this will get created

```
 dataObject:{
   Response:{
      ParentObject:{
        ChildVal:10
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: You can't dynamically create the object structure just from a binding, you'll have to do this yourself somehow (data() or created() hook for example)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to parse the `responseNode` string to convert it into an object and then binding that into an HTML template inside `v-model`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    responseNode: 'dataObject.Response.ParentObject.ChildVal',
    childValue: 10,
    inputValue: null
  },
  mounted() {
    let tempObject = {};
    let container = tempObject;
    this.responseNode.split('.').map((k, i, values) => {
      container = (container[k] = (i == values.length - 1 ? this.childValue : {}))
    });
    this.inputValue = tempObject;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="inputValue.dataObject.Response.ParentObject.ChildVal"/>
</div>
```